# Spark 1.6 explode with null values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe that I am trying to flatten. As part of the process, I want to explode it, so if I have a column of arrays, each value of the array will be used to create a separate row.I know i can use explode function. But, i have a problem, the column contains null value and i use spark 1.6. Here is a example of the type of data and what i want : 
My data :

```
id | ListOfRficAction| RficActionAttachment
_______________________________
1  | Luke            | [baseball, soccer]
2  | Lucy            | null
```

and i want

```
id | ListOfRficAction| RficActionAttachment
_______________________________
1  | Luke            | baseball
1  | Luke            | soccer
2  | Lucy            | null
```

I am using Spark 1.6 (so i can't use explode_outer function) and i try to use explode but i have the following error :

```
 scala.MatchError: [null] (of class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema)
```

i also try  :

```
df.withColumn("likes", explode(
  when(col("likes").isNotNull, col("likes"))
    // If null explode an array<string> with a single null
    .otherwise(array(lit(null).cast("string")))))
```

but my DataFrame schema is a lot complex (i have string and long), so cast function doesn't work. Here is a part of my schema and the error i have :

```
 |-- RficActionAttachment: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- ActivityFileAutoUpdFlg: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ActivityFileDate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ActivityFileDeferFlg: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ActivityFileDockReqFlg: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ActivityFileDockStatFlg: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ActivityFileExt: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ActivityFileName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ActivityFileRev: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ActivityFileSize: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ActivityFileSrcPath: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ActivityFileSrcType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ActivityId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- AttachmentId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Comment: string (nullable = true)
```

User class threw exception:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'CASE WHEN isnotnull(ListOfRficAction.RficAction.ListOfRficActionAttachment.RficActionAttachment) THEN ListOfRficAction.RficAction.ListOfRficActionAttachment.RficActionAttachment ELSE array(ListOfRficAction.RficAction.ListOfRficActionAttachment.RficActionAttachment)'
```

due to data type mismatch: THEN and ELSE expressions should all be same type or coercible to a common type;

Have idea of what i can do ?

Comment: my question is different because i can't use case when with my schema

Comment: the problem is that case when doesn't work for me

Answer (score 2):

First replace all `null` values in the column will `array(null)`, then use `explode`. Using the example dataframe in the question:

```
val df = Seq((1, "Luke", Array("baseball", "soccer")), (2, "Lucy", null))
  .toDF("id", "ListOfRficAction", "RficActionAttachment")

df.withColumn("RficActionAttachment", 
    when($"RficActionAttachment".isNull, array(lit(null)))
    .otherwise($"RficActionAttachment"))
  .withColumn("RficActionAttachment", explode($"RficActionAttachment"))
```

This will give the requested result:

```
+---+----------------+--------------------+
| id|ListOfRficAction|RficActionAttachment|
+---+----------------+--------------------+
|  1|            Luke|            baseball|
|  1|            Luke|              soccer|
|  2|            Lucy|                null|
+---+----------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: thak you @Shaido for answer but as i said i try this and i still have the same error : cannot resolve 'CASE WHEN isnull(ListOfRficAction.RficAction.ListOfRficActionAttachment.RficActionAttachment) THEN array(null) ELSE ListOfRficAction.RficAction.ListOfRficActionAttachment.RficActionAttachment' Maybe due to my dataframe schema

Comment: @MbulaGuyMarcel the dataframe schema shouldn't matter, the above should work if you have an array. Made a small update to the code, can you try again?

Comment: am sorry , it doesn't work

Comment: here is my DF : *********************************isAttachment
+--------+--------------------+--------------------------+
| AssetId|    ListOfRficAction|ListOfRficActionAttachment|
+--------+--------------------+--------------------------+
|1-KTOUUY|[WrappedArray([2,...|                      null|
|1-KTOUUY|[WrappedArray([2,...|      [WrappedArray([Y,...|
+--------+--------------------+--------------------------+ and i try to flat ListOfRficActionAttachment

Comment: @MbulaGuyMarcel from your error message, it looks like the `.otherwise($"RficActionAttachment")` part in the code above does not give an array.  It's is necessary to do it in two stages as above code. You could also try using `
df.withColumn("RficActionAttachment", explode_outer($"RficActionAttachment"))` which should achieve the same thing.